# How to push the 1) find content, 2) replaced content and 3)count

Tags: perl

I need to find greek characters and replace that corresponding values and its replaced counting numbers: (I need to do get this from more 100 replacements)

This is my coding:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @grkChars = qw(alpha beta gamma); 
my $eachGrk = join "|", @grkChars;  #Greek Characters

my $str = 'Trp $\mathbf{R}^a$ locates \alpha \beta distantly $\mathrm{R}^a$ from $\mathit{R}^a$ cys25 in both \gamma and cathepsin K, with \alpha high and moderate $\mathbb{R}^1H$ strengths, respectively. The protein $\mathds{R}^a$ modification $\mathds{R}^1H$ largely \beta affects the binding sites and stability \gamma of the \gamma peptides, and the effects depend on \alpha the elemental compositions of the peptides';

my $count = $str=~s{\\($eachGrk)}{\\\{$1\}}g && print "Content: $&\n";

print "Total Count: $count\n";
```

My Output:

```
Content: \alpha
Total Count: 1
```

Expected output is:

```
\alpha changed to \{alpha} and count 3
\beta changed to \{{beta}} and count 2
\gamma changed to \[gamma] and count 3
```

Could you please someone will advice on this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you expect your program to print `changed to` if there is no code to do that? :)

Comment: How do you create the different replacements `\{alpha}`,  `\{{beta}}`, and `\[gamma]`?

Comment: @simbabque: That's correct. I didn't mentioned in the code. But we have an output for the user end to expose the report like that only.

Comment: @Borodin: The replacement value's sometimes might be hard coded and getting values in *INI files means user input

Comment: @ssr1012: So you removed a statement from the middle of a seven-line program? I'm afraid I'm struggling to believe that.

Comment: @ssr1012: But you hard-code the replacement as `\\\{$1\}`. If you won't fully describe the process and your code isn't even representative of what you really need to do then we can't really help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "too broad" because there is no proper specification and the sample code doesn't come close to doing what has been described in comments.

Comment: *"The replacement value's sometimes might be hard coded and getting values in *INI files means user input"* So that information, together with *proper details*, need to be *in your question*.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: @ssr1012: You had completely changed your question. I have rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 2):

Although you could do something like create an *executable* replacement that increments a hash field instead of a global `$count` variable. it is best to keep things simple. You need to replace the words individually if you want to count them individually. Forget creating a compound regex pattern and just iterate over the array of words

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @grkChars = qw/ alpha beta gamma /;

my $str = 'Trp $\mathbf{R}^a$ locates \alpha \beta distantly $\mathrm{R}^a$ from $\mathit{R}^a$ cys25 in both \gamma and cathepsin K, with \alpha high and moderate $\mathbb{R}^1H$ strengths, respectively. The protein $\mathds{R}^a$ modification $\mathds{R}^1H$ largely \beta affects the binding sites and stability \gamma of the \gamma peptides, and the effects depend on \alpha the elemental compositions of the peptides';

my $total = 0;

for my $grk ( @grkChars ) {

    next unless my $count = $str =~ s{\\($grk)}{\\\{$1\}}g;

    printf "\\%s changed to \\{%s} and count %d\n", $1, $1, $count;
    $total += $count;
}

print "Total Count: $total\n";
```

Comment: Please _printf "\\%s changed to \\{%s} and count %d\n", $1, $1, $count;_ In this line if the second `$1` might be different content then how can I print the replaced value.

Comment: @ssr1012: Then you put the different content in its place.

Comment: As per the requirement I have raised the question. However simply I want to know in perl _s{\\($grk)}{\\\{$1\}}g_ we can get finding value `($grk) = $1` how can we get replacement value in `\\\{$1\}`??? Might be stupid question but I want to know there is any chance to get ?

Comment: You had completely changed your question. Don't do that. I have rolled back your changes. If your question is inherently wrong then you should delete it. If you have a different question then *ask a new question*.

Comment: I couln't able to delete the question. Please suggest.